# Constructor method try to init insatnce variable from subclass get StackOverflowError

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I need to fill the user in Person because is mandatory in DB, but User is a child of Person and I get java.lang.StackOverflowError

User is a Person
Person has a User

I know that is a recursion problem, but I save User in Person to know who has created that person.

I think it is a design problem, but how to solve this?
I'd like to save a default value for this, because database requieres that field.

**Class Person**

```
public class Person {
  private long idPerson;
  //mandatory field in database
  private User useredt;
  public Person() {
    useredt = new User("test");
  }
  ...
}
```

**Class User**

```
public class User extends Person {
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private Boolean enabled = false;

  public User() {
  }
  ...
}
```

**Failure trace**

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.getOffsets(Unknown Source)
    at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.getOffsets(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Calendar.setTimeInMillis(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Calendar.createCalendar(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Calendar.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.javalabs.web.dao.Person.<init>(Person.java:56)
    at com.javalabs.web.dao.User.<init>(User.java:72)
    at com.javalabs.web.dao.Person.<init>(Person.java:60)
    at com.javalabs.web.dao.User.<init>(User.java:72)
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: 99.99% of all cases of StackOverflowError are caused by infinite recursion.

Comment: How to avoid the recursion but initialize the useredt in Person? I have a database with People and a reduced group of this (User) that can create Person. And I save the User whose has created the Person.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have *infinite Recursion*.

`new User()` implicitly calls `Person()` (super-class constructor), in which you have again called `new User()` which again calls `Person()` and so on.

PS : from a design perspective, if a User *is a* (inheritance) person, then I don't think it is wise to use a person *has-a* (composition) user.

Answer (score 0):

What did you expect? You created an infinite recursion in your constructor calls.

You can overcome this problem by not creating the instance of User in the Person constructor. Instead, call a setter method that would assign its value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is a result of bad coding. You have to think again. In your current code resulting infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Because User is a subclass of Person, every User also has a User (which has a User, ad infinitum) - which is probably not what you want. I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve, but having a User attribute in the Person which is set in the constructor is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the recursion is caused by the Person constructor creating an instance of the User class. The User constructor implicitly calls the Person constructor, with an implicit "super()" that the compiler adds in automatically.  So it goes into an infinate loop.

You have to design your code so as to avoid this problem.

.

Are the Person and User classes stored in the same table in the database, or separate tables?

If the User and Person classes are stored in the same table in the database, and the "User userdt" column is non-nullable, then that means that some User/Person record(s) must point to themselves.  This tells me that the User class' constructor needs to start with a "super(this);" line, to say that the User for this Person is this User/Person themselves.  The Person class' constructor would need a "User" parameter.

If the User and Person are two separate tables, then why do you have the User class extending the Person class?  Well, assuming that this is what you want, the solution is still the same as above.

Comment: All recursion must be coded with an exit condition.  Otherwise you'll have an infinite loop, through infinite recursion, which will result in stack overflow, which is the name of this site, for good reason.  ;->